# error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'int *' to 'int'

Tags: c, pointers

I want to compare a number with a address.
Here's the code.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main (void) {
    int a = 1;
    printf("%#x\n", &a);  // The address of a is 0x18ff44
    int  b = 0x18ff44;
    if (b == &a) {        //error
       printf("no\n"); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know whether I can compare a number with a address.

error: error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'int *' to 'int'

I did some research and I have two hypothesises:

- maybe because different datatype can't compare.

  But I tried to compare datatype of float with char, and the code is compielred correct.
- I learned the compiler error c2446 of MSDN. The translation is that "The compiler is unable to convert type1 to type2. "

My hypothesises is that when execute relational operation ,the compiler need to covert type1 to type2. But the conversion of 'int *' to 'int' does not make sense. **My question: Is this hypothesis correct? And if it's not, why does that happens?**

Compiler Info: VC 6.0 downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com

Comment: First of all if you want to print a pointer, you should use the `"%p"` format, and it must be a `void *` (an explicit cast is needed). Read e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for more information.

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. To print a pointer, use `%p` which expects a `void *`.

Comment: As for the error, it should be quite clear: You have two values of incompatible types that you want to compare.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is Visual C 6.0. It would be miraculous if it was fully C89 compliant never mind modern C standards compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `b` (`int`) is *incompatible* with the type of the expression `&a` (`int *`).  The fix is simple - declare `b` as an `int *`:

```
int *b = (int *) 0x18ff44; // literal will have integral, non-pointer type,
...                        // so the cast is necessary
if ( b == &a )  // int * == int *
{
  ...
}
```

Now the expressions have compatible types, and the error will go away.

To *print* pointer values, use the `%p` conversion specifier as so:

```
printf( "&a = %p\n", (void *) &a );
```

This is one of the very few (if not only) places in C were casting a `void *` is necessary.

**EDIT**

To answer the larger question, *why* is `int` incompatible with `int *`?

The `int` datatype is a signed type, and is only *guaranteed* to represent values in the range `[-32767,32767]`.  It may be able to represent a wider range of values (and on most modern implementations, it does, usually `[-232, 232-1]`), but it may or may not be able to represent all possible pointer values.  A pointer value can be converted to an `int` value and vice versa, but the result is not guaranteed to be meaningful or well-defined.

Representation of pointer types is basically up to the implementation, and that representation may not even be a scalar value.  It may even be different for different pointer types (although `void *` and `char *` must have the same representation and alignment).  So a direct comparison between an `int` and a pointer type may not be meaningful.  The implementation may use the same word size and representation for both under the hood, but since that's not guaranteed to be the case, the language mandates that the types are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main (void) {
    int a = 1;
    printf("%p\n", &a);  // The address of a is 0x18ff44
    int  b = 0x18ff44;
    if (b == (int) &a) {        //no error
       printf("no\n"); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: for sake of generality in 64 bit systems, use this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main (void) {
    int a = 1;
    printf("%p\n", &a);  // The address of a is 0x18ff44
    long long b = 0x18ff44;
    if (b == (long long) &a) {        //no error
       printf("no\n"); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might *seem* to work, but what if a pointer doesn't fit in an `int` (which is typically true on 64-bit systems)? This is generally a really bad way of comparing pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's VC6. It's strictly 32 bit.

Comment: @JeremyP: It's still a really bad way of comparing pointer values.

Comment: @JohnBode Not disputing that. There is no portable way of comparing a literal value to a pointer, that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can compare a variable to an address, but it is very dangerous.

First of all, your code compiles correctly with gcc version 4.6.3. So I assume that compiler error is related to MSVC and can surely be disabled.

Nevertheless,

An address type is `size_t` which can be (usually) 32 or 64 depending on your machine and build environment. An integer on the other hand may be smaller than size_t, not enough to address the entire RAM!

So I suggest you use size_t instead of int (or convert both of your integer and pointer to `size_t`) and then compare them, I assume this is the safest and makes more sense since we are truly comparing two memory pointer types instead of integer and float.

I would do something like this:

```
size_t a_adr = (size_t)&a;
size_t b_adr = (size_t)&b;

if (a_adr == b_adr)
   ..
```

Be careful when dealing with pointers my friend.

Comment: I don't think `size_t` is guaranteed to be big enough to hold a pointer. If the compiler has it `intptr_t` is the correct type. For VC 6 `int` is big enough, although I would have gone with `unsigned long`.

Comment: Why not just declare `b` as an `int *`?